# Removing Ribbon Button but still get linker errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, ribbon

I try to remove a button(I wrongly made a on event handler using wrong parent class) but i still get linker errors about the removed handler even though i remove the button from the ribbon. This is on Visual Studio 2010 Pro with a MFC C++ Project.

EDIT:
For example I have a button with id BtnTargetPS3 and 2 functions

```
void CAboutDlg::OnTargetPS3()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}


void CTheApp::OnBtntargetps3()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}
```

I want the first one removed but when i do it i get linker errors as it still needs it??
When I remove that button I still get linker errors when i remove both of those functions.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question with so little detail.

Comment: Just added more info, thanks for your time

Comment: What error message is displayed by the linker ? This would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a message handler for an event by the wizard causes 3 changes to your source code.

1 - A message routing macro is added inside the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP/END_MESSAGE_MAP` block inside the `.cpp` file.

2 - A code implementation of the handler function as a member function of the class, inside the `.cpp` file.

3 - A prototype declaration of the handler function in the `{{AFX_MSG(ClassName)/}}AFX_MSG` block inside the `.h` file.

Most probably your problem is caused by deleting items 1 and 2 but forgot about item 3.

Answer (score 0):

You removed the button but i assume the function related to the button does still exist.
So search for it and remove the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: No I did remove the function and thats why i get linker errors.